# How do you use Babel Compiled classes inline?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My src/index.js file contains a class:

```
export default class Test {
  constructor() {
    this._name = 'Test';
  }
}
```

Babel then compiles it to an es5 file.
In my index.html file, I want to have something like:

```
<script src="lib/library.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

which is followed by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var test = new Test();
</script>
```

However, I get 'Test' is not defined. How can I use es5 inline js in my index.html, where the class is being exported in a babel compiled file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 modules by design don't pollute the global state with their inner definitions, which also means that you cannot simply access exports without explicitly importing them.

One solution to make your class accessible globally would be by doing so explicitly:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this._name = 'Test';
  }
}

window.Test = Test
```

Now you should be able to instantiate your class anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

By default babel transpiles the class into a module that is only usable inside a Common JS environment.

You can use [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/) though that transforms your module to [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), which will set a global variable accessible in your `<script>` tag.